# How to add load more button for a HTML/CSS page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make a single page website and it will have huge content. Suppose it has 1000 photos on it. I don't want people to wait 5 minutes to load my page. So I wanna add LOAD MORE button on the page bottom.

How to do that with HTML/CSS/JS?

Comment: Where are the photos coming from? Are you grabbing them from the database? We can't really help you when we don't know the source of the photos.

Comment: photos will be hosted on my website.. just like blog posts

Comment: Yes, but how are you adding them to the webpage? With PHP?

Comment: Suppose I have 100 <div> on my page. I want to show 10 at a time and add a a load more page at bottom.

Comment: With HTML/CSS or JS is this posible?

Comment: If the elements are on the page but not shown they are still loaded. Showing only a certain number of them and adding a "Load More" button with Javascript has no use in upping the performance loading-wise.

Comment: elements should be loaded when we click the load more button

Comment: If you don't mind little to no difference in loading time, I have a way for you to do this.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6FzSb/2/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could set all the `div`s' to `display:none;` at first and then use jQuery to show the first 10 (or however many you wish to show):

```
$(function(){
    $("div").slice(0, 10).show(); // select the first ten
    $("#load").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 10).show(); // select next 10 hidden divs and show them
        if($("div:hidden").length == 0){ // check if any hidden divs still exist
            alert("No more divs"); // alert if there are none left
        }
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/bEdfX/).

This saves you the trouble of including an entire plugin when what you want can be achieved in a few lines of code.

Comment: I need to contact you. On Twitter or Facebook.

Comment: Including a plugin might be a good idea, instead of loading entire database to a div.

Comment: Sorry to revive an old post, but I just came across this wanting to do something similar.  Could someone clarify if this actually reduces load time?  From my understanding, this method would still load every div on page load, just not show it, which would defeat the purpose of the "load more" bar, right?  Unless i'm mistaken...

Comment: This solution is actually very bad for load times. To have a true "load more" button, you want to look at AJAX. You basically want to make a request to your server (capture the request with PHP or another backend language), go through your database, and return the additional data already packed up as HTML content.

Comment: What about for this 
` <div class="cbp-item graphic" id="product">
                                        product details
                                    </div> `

 what will be the solution for this div to repeat? @Purag

Answer (score 1):

The closest i can get reading your question, you want the effect which google and facebook uses nowadays to load posts.

Visit [infinite-scroll.com](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)
They have your answer.

Comment: @SaifulIslam, as you are new here, I will remind you to accept an answer as accepted, so that other visitors who have the same problem will know which solution worked. Just click the little `right` icon on the left side of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

## myList id the id of my ul tag.

x=9 gives 9 views from first only further you can load again at a time 3 more will be loaded.

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
        size_li = $j("#myList li").size();
        x=9;
        $j('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
        $j('#loadMore').click(function () {
            x= (x+3 <= size_li) ? x+3 : size_li;
            $j('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it with Ajax and Django. Idk it might be somewhat helpful to see how you can go about doing it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
.not-visible {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<div id="pic_box"></div>
<div id="spinner-box" class="not-visible"><div class="spinner-border text-dark" role="status"></div></div>
<div id="loadmore-box">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="loadbtn">
    Load More
    </button>
</div>


<script>

const pics_box = document.getElementById('pic-box')
const loadbtn = document.getElementById('loadbtn')
const spinner_box = document.getElementById('spinner-box')
const loadmore_box = document.getElementById('loadmore-box')
let visible = 3




const handleGetData = () => {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post-json/${visible}/`,
    success: function(response){
        max_size = response.max
        const data = response.data
        spinner_box.classList.remove('not-visible')
        setTimeout(()=>{
              spinner_box.classList.add('not-visible')
                data.map(picz=>{
                    console.log(pics.id)
                    pics_box.innerHTML += `<div class="card p-3 mt-3 mb-3">

                                                <br>

                                                ${pics.id}

                                            </div>`
                })
        }, 1000)
        data.map(comment=>{
        console.log()
        })
        if(max_size){
            console.log('done')
            loadmore_box.innerHTML = "<h4>No more pics to load</h4>"
        }
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.log(error)
    }

})
}
handleGetData()

loadbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
visible += 3
handleGetData()
} )

</script>
```

That would be for the Template, and then for the views.py if your using django,

```
class PostJsonListView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        upper = kwargs.get('num_pics')
        lower = upper - 3
        pics = list(Pics.objects.values()[lower:upper])
        pics_size = len(Pics.objects.all())
        size = True if upper >= pics_size else False
        return JsonResponse({'data': comment, 'max': size}, safe=False)
```

This is my first answer so...idk if this is how i have to do it

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you have a backend server or something like that, but anyway, you can try some javascript template engine like [jQuery Template](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/), [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) etc.

and load the images dynamically by js would be a solution :)