# How to change "load more" button by "no more divs" in this example

Tags: javascript, button, jsfiddle

I found a [nice solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8352551/4382830) for a "load more..." link.

In the referenced answer, there is a [JSFidlle example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/bEdfX/). How can I change the text "load more" to "no more divs" if there are no hidden divs left? At this time I have an alert, but I prefer to change text "Load more" to "No more divs".

My code at the moment:

```
$(function(){
    $("div").slice(0, 10).show(); // select the first ten
    $("#load").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 10).show(); // select next 10 hidden divs and show them
        if($("div:hidden").length == 0){ // check if any hidden divs still exist
            alert("No more divs"); // alert if there are none left
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you requested, the link will simply be changed to "No more divs" by using the below code:

```
$(function(){
    $("div").slice(0, 10).show(); // select the first ten
    $("#load").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 10).show(); // select next 10 hidden divs and show them
        if($("div:hidden").length == 0){ // check if any hidden divs still exist
            $("#load").text("No more divs"); // change the text of the link to "No more divs"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: just a question sir, can we have "no more divs" without clickable link ?