# Where should keyboard focus go when a ‘load more’ button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, lazy-loading

Where should keyboard focus go when a ‘load more’ button is clicked? On websites showing this functionality; either focus is moved to the top of the page when the button is clicked, or focus moves beyond the new content.

I find these methods problematic because how do keyboard users, and assistive technology users know where the new content is started—and easily move to this point.

I am looking for a solution, and although I can think of a couple of ways to address this, I am unsure of the best approach from an accessibility perspective.

1. Focus is moved to the start of the new content. This could be
   achieved using a tabindex-1 and scripting to set focus.
2. New content loads after the ‘load more’ the button remains in
   position and focus remains on the button. At the end of the new
   content a new ‘load more’ button appears.

*I'm looking for best practice functionality that is also accessible*

**Sites already checked for a 'Load more' content button functionality**

2. **Show More Button** https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/interactivity-dynamic-content/show_more_button/
3. **Adding a Load More Button to your Content** https://www.solodev.com/blog/web-design/adding-a-load-more-button-to-your-content.stml
4. **How to add load more button for a HTML/CSS page?**
   [How to add load more button for a HTML/CSS page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352372/how-to-add-load-more-button-for-a-html-css-page)

Comment: I think that this question might be better suited to https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I will post to ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single answer to this question, but there's some [guidance from W3 regarding the opening and closing of modals](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#dialog_modal) (which are also a 'wholesale' shift in what's available to the UI, and therefore comparable).

Also there is [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/client-rendered-accessibility/), and [these survey results](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-07-11-user-testing-accessible-client-routing/) (both from the esteemed Marcy Sutton) which may help make the right choice.

As always, testing with a representative group of your own actual users, and using analytics will serve your users better than designing for imaginary or 'generic' users.

Comment: Couple of points; the audience is known and includes people who rely on a screen reader and users with motor/ dexterity disability. The load more button is not related to a modal dialog, but a button that adds more products or articles below the visible ones. Thanks for your suggestions @brennanyoung the survey results are useful.

Comment: The info on focus management in the ‘this article’ are also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We must consider if whether or not the new content is part of a group. A group is, based on HTML semantics, a list (unordered or ordered list) or a group of radio buttons/checkboxes (fieldset).

### The new content is not part of a group

The user already goes through the visible elements so, when he clicks on 'load more' button, moving the focus to the first element of the new content is the best solution. The user will see the new content as an extend of the visible content.

### The new content is part of a group

The difference occurs mainly on the screen reader user. The screen reader announces how much elements are part of the group. By clicking on the 'load more' button, the amount of elements in the group raises (visible elements + new content). In this case, the screen reader should know how much elements are in the group and the new content. I propose two solutions that should be test with screen reader users.

- Goes through visible elements twice
  Move the focus on the first visible element will update the amount of elements in the group but the user will go through the visible elements twice.
- Announces the end of the loading of the new content
  Add an aria-live region which announces the end of the loading of the new content and move the focus to the first element of the new content.

Comment: The second point is the better option for screen reader users IMO